# Query was empty SQL=

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, insert, joomla3.0

I have this error and I dont know why.
I have 3 similar requests and the second one doesnt work.
Im using Joomla 3.

```
$url = $json_data['url'];
$main_dir_uri = 'site/'. $mob_url;
$mob_url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $main_dir_uri;
$publish = true;
$call_btn = true;
$multilang = false;
$sinchronization = mysql_real_escape_string('23:00:00');
$columns1 = array('datecreate', 'dateedit');
$columns2 = array('siteurl', 'mobsiteurl', 'uridir', 'publish', 'multilang', 'callbtn', 'sinchronization');
$columns3 = array('idusers', 'datecreate', 'dateedit');
$values1 = array("NOW()", "NOW()");
$values2 = array($url, $mob_url, $main_dir_uri, $publish, $multilang, $call_btn, $sinchronization);
$values3 = array($user_id, "NOW()", "NOW()");

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query1 = $db->getQuery(true);
$query1
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__sites'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns1))
    ->values(implode(',', $values1));
$db->setQuery($query1);
$db->query();

$query2 = $db->getQuery(true);
$query2
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__sites_data'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns2))
    ->values(implode(',', $values2));
$query2 = $db->getQuery(true);
$db->setQuery($query2);
$db->query();

$query3 = $db->getQuery(true);
$query3
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__sites_users'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns3))
    ->values(implode(',', $values3));
$db->setQuery($query3);
$db->query();

if($db->getErrorMsg()) {
    print_r($db->getErrorMsg());
}
```

I've checked all values, they are ok. What's the problem can be?

Comment: Have you tried echoing all $query values to the page to see which one is empty?

Comment: Perhaps you should check `$db->getErrorMsg()` after _each_ query instead of at the end, to narrow down which one caused an error.

Comment: `$sinchronization = mysql_real_escape_string('23:00:00');` is suspect.  `mysql_real_escape_string()` will result in an empty string value if there is no active `mysql_connect()` connection resource. Does your framework provide an active connection resource?  In any case, there is no need to escape a static string like `'23:00:00'`

Comment: Error is in $query2.
mysql_real_escape_string('23:00:00') gaves string. i've checked it by echo $sinchronization;

Comment: i've echoed all query values. they all are ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `$query2 = $db->getQuery(true);` that is wiping out $query2.